# How to call http://metadata.ggogle.internal from within web app loaded over https

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, metadata, google-cloud-run, mixed-content

I have an Angular web app running on Cloud Run (nginx webserver) ([more info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257237/how-to-access-gcp-secret-manager-from-angular-9-web-app-service/61270548#61270548)) from which I want to get access token from the GCP metadata server. I have tried to make a call to https://metadata.google.internal ( using curl from Cloud Shell) but the connection was rejected. Calls to HTTP are working well.

When I make the call from my app (which is loaded over https) to the metadata server over HTTP - logically I get a mixed content error. When trying to access the metadata server over HTTPS - I am getting error 504 Gateway timeout, I assume due to the reason that the metadata server refuses the calls on HTTPS.

I will really appreciate any idea of how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL endpoint `metadata.google.internal` is only accessible from inside the instance (Cloud Run). This endpoint is not accessible outside of the instance such as via an HTTP or HTTPS call. A clue is the TLD (Top Level Domain) `internal`.

If you want to access this endpoint remotely via a web browser, you will need to make a request from the browser to Cloud Run (an endpoint in your code) which then makes the internal request to the metadata server and returns the response to the client.

Comment: Thanks, John. That sounds so logical now :)... let me try to see the solution.

Comment: Do not let external users accces `metadata.google.internal`. It contains token endpoints that can let visitors gain access to your account.

Comment: The initial idea was targeting to access the `metadata.google.internal` for getting secret values from the Secret Manager for usage in the front-end code only. No end-user access to them was planned. After John's advice above - I am accessing now the metadata server from the backend. But that is a good reminder. Thanks, AhmetB